# Can we do real time replication based on a condition on column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-replication

Currently we are using Oracle SQL and replicating data. After doing some analysis we found out that we are not using most of the data that we are replicating. To optimize this we thought to replicate data based on column conditions.  Can this be achieved in Oracle DB? If so what strategy can we use here?

Comment: What replication software are you using? GoldenGate, SharePlex, Data Guard, or something else?

Comment: I have no idea what our DB team is using. I am just learning.